# Different Facebook comments system for main domain and subdomain

Tags: facebook, comments, subdomain

I have got two websites.

MainPage: 
Domain:  example.com
facebook_appId: **12345** 
I would like to see the collection of the comments:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/**12345**/ 
embeded facebook comments code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=12345&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/article_title" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

SubPage: 
Domain: subdomain.example.com
facebook_appId: **56789** 
I would like to see the collection of the comments:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/**56789**/ 
embeded facebook comments code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/hu_HU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=56789&autoLogAppEvents=1';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://subdomain.example.com/another_article_title" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

I would like to use both website a Facebook Comments Plugin, but I would like to separate these two site comments. I already tried to add different app_id, but the system always adds all comments to **example.com** 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/**12345**/

I already checked here, but I can't found solution:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: You don’t need a different app id for that; you only need to point the comments plugin to the right URLs in each case, _and_ those URLs of course need to be “separate entities”, meaning you can’t have og:url or canonical pointing from one to the other.

Comment: Please open my question, I have corrected it.
Or is there something else missing?

Comment: I can only vote to re-open your question, but it needs a couple of other members to do the same. Besides that, you have not added that much useful information though ... OK, the data-href might be pointing to different URLs now, but you still need to check the other stuff I mentioned.